# How to make an attribute read-only in serializers in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have a serializer.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyClass
```

My model class is:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey("Employee", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    work_done = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I want employee attribute to be read-only and should only show this value in it's field:

```
employee = Employee.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

How can I do this in serializers?

Answer (score 0):

```
extra_kwargs = {
            'employee': {'read_only': True}
       }
```

you can make it using extra_kwargs it overrides existing model behaviours

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it read-only by mentioning it on the serializer, and show the current user's value by modifying the init method in the following way :

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = models.MyClass
    read_only_fields = [
        'employee',
    ]

def get_employee(self, instance) -> Any:
    employee = None
    request = self.context.get('request')
    if request and hasattr(request, 'user'):
        employee = Employee.objects.get(request.user)

    # if you want to show serialize value of employee
    # then write a EmployeeSerializer and add following blocked code 

    # if employee:
    #     serializer = EmployeeSerializer(user, many=False)
    #     employee = serializer.data
    return employee
```